# Application session expires on multiple tomcat instances with same war name

Tags: java, tomcat7

I have deployed 'app.war' in tomcat A and tomcat B. When I login to **app** via **tomcat A** instance, it successfully logs in. And when i try to login to **app** via **tomcat B** instance in same browser it logs in successfully but tomcat A instance apps session logs out automatically. I tried same apps on different browser they are working fine but not in same browser.

Any idea, how to fix it?

Comment: so it sounds liek a browser problem?  Which browser are you using?

Comment: Well it looks like a cookie problem. Without more information on what your login system is, I cannot be 100% sure, but it does smell like it.

It is current that sessions are maintained using a cookie on browser. All major browsers allow you to list your current cookies. You should note what cookies exists in your browser (or clear them all), log to app on tomcatA and note the new cookie (domain, name and value), then on tomcatB and see what happened. It is necessary to help you to fix the problem.

Comment: I am using firefox and tried on chrome as well but session expires.